# function dose not run

Tags: node.js, passport.js

when I go to '/login/github' the code does not run in the call back function

github config.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GitHupStrategy = require("passport-github").Strategy
const {gitHup} = require('./config')


passport.use(new GitHupStrategy({
  clientID: gitHup.clientID,
  clientSecret: gitHup.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: gitHup.callbackURL,
},(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  console.log(profile)
}))
```

login router.js

```
const experss = require("express");
const router = experss.Router();
const loginController = require("../controllers/loginControllre");
const passport = require("passport");
const { gitHup } = require("../config/config");

router.get("/login/github",passport.authenticate('github', { scope: ['user'] }));
router.get(gitHup.callbackURL, passport.authenticate('github'));

module.exports = router;
```

```
                                                           .
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.